# PostgreSQL sending wrong queries responses

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a frontend that keep sending a request to a backend
several time per seconds.
For the most time it works OK.

But for some reason that I didn't understand
Postgres keeps sending queries with a wrong order

Example: I use the same query to retrieve information about 3 different clients, information like users.

I have a table that contains the Users information and one of the info it's the client from what this user came
I've create a dashboard to keep track in real time the total users by clients

But sometimes the info from Client A appears on client B, Client C on Client A, Client C on B
and the only thing that I do is a select changing the WHERE client = "A" or B or C

So my dashboard keeps flickering, alternating with the right data and wrong ones

My backend is NodeJS with Express that communicates with my Postgres server

Update: The query that I'm using

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM trackers 
WHERE "client" = '${Client}'
```

Update 2:  I'm using a pool of connections in my backend, once the back is sent to the front the backend closes the connection.

Maybe because I'm sending too many requests from the same place the pool is mixing the responses

I'm using the NPM pg package

Comment: You need to show the query.

Comment: I think you need to turn on as much logging as possible for both client and server to see if you have some timing issues or similar

Comment: It would be helpful to show all your JavaScript, because the problem is almost certainly in your code, not Postgres or the connection pool. The problem is you are making some kind of mistake in how you are matching the queries or the results to the Client dashboard. Please try to create a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but at least show the code that makes the calls, gets the results, and finds the right DOM element to update with the results.